# How to hide dynamically created button?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button that is created dynamically in C#. Now I want this button to hide when it is clicked. How would I do this?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
 if (hide_button.Click == true)
                {
                    hide_button.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                }
```

Comment: 'it doesn't work' is a really bad way to describe a problem - what happens? Exceptions? Unexpected behaviour? Explosions?

Comment: Where are you doing that? `hide_button.Click == true` makes no sense... `Click` is an event, not a boolean property. You should be subscribing to it and managing the `Visibility` in the handler.

Comment: @goobering,  By "doesn't work" he obviously means the button is not hidden as he expects. At least I got that message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure the below line works for you.

```
if (hide_button.Click==true)
```

try removing this line and it will work. as the event is not equatable to a Boolean value.

This code worked for me

```
Button buton = new Button();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        buton.Click += Buton_Click;
        grid.Children.Add(buton);
    }

    private void Buton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        buton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.Click += (sender,e) => 
    {
        if (button.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    };
```

or

```
button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    else
        button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: button.Visible = !button.Visible; is this line compile ?

Comment: lol um no it needs to be either Visibility.Hidden or .Collapsed

Comment: `Visible` is a WinForms property, in WPF you use either `IsVisible` (which is read-only) or `Visibility` (which is an enum, not a boolean)... Other than that, this answer is perfectly valid

Comment: Is there a way to click on a collapsed button? If not the visibility toggle makes no sense at all